# Trivial but confusing javascript in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The author of [this tutorial](http://www.befundoo.com/university/tutorials/angularjs-directives-tutorial/) describes the following code as such: "every element of stars array has an object with value ‘filled‘ that is evaluated to true or false based on the value of scope.ratingValue that we get from the DOM."

```
directive('fundooRating', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<ul class="rating">' +
              '<li ng-repeat="star in stars" class="filled">' +
                  '\u2605' +
              '</li>' +
            '</ul>',
    scope: {
      ratingValue: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.stars = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
      scope.stars.push({filled: i < scope.ratingValue});
  }
}
```

As a js newbie, I still can't make heads or tails on how to "read" that last line. From the code the only place where filled is mentioned that I can see is the css file and the template here. So there is no bool value that I can see and the syntax is a bit confusing for me. How should i think about it?[github code](https://github.com/Fundoo-Solutions/angularjs-tutorials/blob/master/directives/rating/rating.js)

Comment: I think there might be a typo here: class should something along the lines of ng-class="{filled:filled}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source and the template says:

```
'<li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star" ng-click="toggle($index)">'
```

When the [ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive is given an object, it checks every one of its properties, and if it's truhty, it adds the property name as a classname. Exemple:

`ng-class="{filled:true, bold:false}"` will evaluate `class="filled"`.

So this last line sets the 'filled' status of the star, and so the filled class will be put only to the scope.max -nth elements.